# Porque o template do mvc com identity ultiliza async nas controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Quando é criando um template *ASP NET MVC 5* com *Identity* por exemplo o método Login utiliza o async para não travar a Thread principal.

Eu não entendi qual é a necessidade de fazer isso sendo que após o usuário clicar em fazer login na (tela de login) view ele não vai ter que esperar de qualquer forma a resposta do servidor na mesma (tela de login) view para saber se o login foi aceito ou não?

Nesse caso faz diferença ter esse método com async ou sem async? Isso só me faz sentido se o login de um usuário afetar o login de outro usuário que esta em outra maquina, outro endereço. Ele afeta o login de outro usuário se tiver sem o async?

Desculpa se a pergunta estiver muito complicada mas é isso que eu não entendi :/

Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que já tem uma resposta pra isso aqui no site, só não tenho como procurar agora.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, eu não entendi por exemplo no método Login que utiliza o "async" qual a necessidade de utilizar ele (async) sendo que o usuário precisa de qualquer forma esperar o retorno desse método para acessar o sistema? se nesse caso ele tem que esperar, não tanto faz ser assíncrono ou não?

Comment: Os posts linkados respondem sua pergunta. Basicamente, não tem nada a ver com o usuário esperar ou não o retorno, é algo bem diferente disso.